# Is it possible to use smooth functions as part of a nonlinear regression?

Tags: bayesian, multiple-regression, interaction, smoothing, brms

#### Background

I am fitting nonlinear regressions with a single response and two predictors. I know the relationship between the response and each of the predictors, but I do not know how they interact. I am trying to build understand their interaction to build process-based models that incorporate it. In the meantime, I would like to adequately describe their interaction using some mix of parametric and smooth functions, if possible.

#### Problem

Let's take the [Monod equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monod_equation) from microbiology, which is a saturating function describing how microbial growth $\mu$ changes with nutrient concentration $R$:

$$ \mu =\mu _{\max }{R \over K_{s}+R} $$

$R$ is the only predictor (/independent variable) here. Let's say we have this curve measured at several different levels of a second continuous predictor (call it $S$). If $S$ was categorical and these were curves from a set of different species (for example), the best solution would probably be to make this a hierarchical model. Since $S$ is continuous, $\mu_{max} $ and $K_{s}$ are both continuous functions of $S$ and I'm not sure that a hierarchical model makes sense. **Instead, is it possible to make these two parameters smooth functions of $S$?** Perhaps a different way to phrase this problem is: **how can I do nonlinear regression with some smooth parameters?** I recognise that the best solution would be to modify the equation to describe the specific mathematical dependence - we just do not have the knowledge to do this right now and a smooth function is a compromise.

Here's some example code showing how I would fit the basic equation with the `R` package `brms` (the fitting procedure doesn't have to be Bayesian, but I prefer it). My goal is to modify this to make $\mu_{max} $ and $K_{s}$ smooth functions of $S$, iff this a reasonable thing to do. I'm open to alternate approaches if this does not make sense.

```r
library(brms)

# set seed
set.seed(87)

# define model with interaction
double_monod <- function(nut1, nut2, mu_max, k1, k2){
  gr <- mu_max * (nut1 / (nut1 + k1)) * (nut2 / (nut2 + k2))
  gr
}

# simulate dataset based on model
dat <- expand.grid(R = c(1, 10, 20, 40, 80, 160),
                   S = c(1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 30))

dat$growthrate <- double_monod(dat$R, dat$S, 1, 20, 5) + 
  rnorm(nrow(dat), 0, 0.1)

# set prior
prior1 <- prior(exponential(2), nlpar = "mumax", lb = 0) +
  prior(exponential(0.1), nlpar = "ks", lb = 0) 

# fit model to basic monod equation with just one predictor(R)
# note that this entirely ignores the second predictor S
fit1 <- brm(bf(growthrate ~ ((mumax * R) / (R + ks)),
               mumax + ks ~ 1, nl = TRUE),
            data = dat, prior = prior1, iter = 50000,
            control = list(adapt_delta = 0.95))
```

Comment: The example data is missing an S continuous predictor so I cannot test this (which means this might not even be valid brms syntax) but what about using this brms formula: `bf(growthrate ~  (mumax * R / (R + ks)), mumax ~ s(S), ks ~ s(S), nl = TRUE)`. `s()` denotes a smoother in brms.

Comment: @dipetkov Many thanks! You're right, I should have simulated a dataset with the second predictor as well. I have updated this with a better example now. I've also tried out your suggested code and it works exactly as I hoped, after a little tweaking (need to constrain k for smooth terms because of small sample size). And I see that I can examine the individual smooth responses by using conditional_smooths(). If you'd like to add this as an answer, I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your brms formula specifies a simple model for (the mean of) the maximum growth rate $\mu_{max}$ and the half-velocity $k_s$:

```r
bf(
  ...,
  mumax + ks ~ 1,
  ...
)
```

This is equivalent to:

```r
bf(
  ...,
  mumax ~ 1,
  ks ~ 1,
  ...
)
```

which I find more readable. It means brms will estimate $\operatorname{E}(\mu_{max}) = \beta_{\mu_{max}}$ and $\operatorname{E}(k_s) = \beta_{k_s}$.

Alternatively, you can specify a more complex model for the maximum growth rate and half-velocity as functions of the continuous predictor $S$:

```r
bf(
  ...,
  mumax ~ s(S, k = 2),
  ks ~ s(S, k = 2),
  ...
)
```

[brms](https://paul-buerkner.github.io/brms/) uses the [mgcv](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mgcv/index.html) smoothers `s(...)` and `t2(...)`. I've specified `s(S, k = 2)` which corresponds a thin-plate spline ("tp" is the default type) with two basis functions.

Here are the fitted smooths, plotted with `?brms::conditional_smooths`.

[image]

NB: There are issues with the fit. I got warnings about Rhats > 1.05 and divergent transitions after warmup. So more work is needed to choose priors carefully and potentially to specify a different form for the relationship of $\mu_{max}$ and $k_s$ on $S$.

Also: Each chain took ~5min to sample.

---

The full specification of the nonlinear growth model with smooth terms for maximum growth rate and half-velocity.

```r
fit2 <- brm(
  bf(
    growthrate ~ (mumax * R / (R + ks)),
    mumax ~ s(S, k = 2),
    ks ~ s(S, k = 2),
    nl = TRUE
  ),
  data = dat, prior = prior1, # update the prior to get a better fit
  control = list(adapt_delta = 0.95),
  iter = 50000, seed = 1234
)

plot(conditional_smooths(fit2), ask = FALSE)
```